# Church numerals

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

There are 4 exercises in Poly module related to Church numerals:

```
Definition cnat := forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X -> X.
```

As far as I understand cnat is a function that takes a function f(x), it's argument x and returns it's value for this argument: f(x).

Then there are 4 examples for 0, 1, 2 and 3 represented in Church notation.

But how to solve this? I understand that we must apply the function one more time. The value returned by cnat will be the argument. But how to code it? Use a recursion?

```
Definition succ (n : cnat) : cnat
  (* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH ":= _your_definition_ ." *). Admitted.
```

Update

I tried this:

```
Definition succ (n : cnat) : cnat :=
match n with
| zero => one
| X f x => X f f(x) <- ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a Church numeral is a function of two arguments (or three if you also count the type). The arguments are a function `f` and a start value `x0`.  The Church numeral applies `f` to `x0`  some number of times. `Four f x0` would correspond to  `f (f (f (f x0)))`  and `Zero f x0` would ignore `f` and just be `x0`.

For the successor of `n`, remember that `n` will apply any function `f` for you `n` times, so if your task is to create a function applies some `f` on some `x0`  `n+1` times, just leave the bulk of the work to the church numeral `n`, by giving it your `f` and `x0`, and then finish off with one more application of `f` to the result returned by `n`.

You won't be needing any `match` because functions are not inductive data types that can be case analysed upon...

Comment: I found the answer myself using Users help. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the `Definition` for `succ` in the following way:

```
Definition succ (n : cnat) : cnat :=
    fun (X : Type) (f : X -> X) (x : X) => f (n X f x).
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the same solution

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand cnat is a function that takes a function f(x), it's argument x and returns it's value for this argument: f(x).

Note that `cnat` itself isn't a function. Instead, `cnat` is the *type* of all such functions. Also note that elements of `cnat` take `X` as an argument as well. It'll help to keep the definition of `cnat` in mind.

```
Definition succ (n: cnat): cnat.
Proof.
  unfold cnat in *. (* This changes `cnat` with its definition everywhere *)
  intros X f x.
```

After this, our goal is just `X`, and we have `n : forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X -> X`, `X`, `f` and `x` as premises.

If we applied `n` to `X`, `f` and `x` (as `n X f x`), we would get an element of `X`, but this isn't quite what we want, since the end result would just be `n` again. Instead, we need to apply `f` an extra time somewhere. Can you see where? There are two possibilities.

Comment: I tried to play with your code, but it's the first time when I see a definition being made with proof. I don't think it was in the book before. `Qed` at the end doesn't work.

Comment: "Instead, we need to apply f an extra time somewhere" - we need to apply it to x. But how to write it in coq syntax?

Comment: For a simple definition like this, proof mode is mainly useful for exploring the types of things and experimenting. Once you have the final definition, you can put it in `:=` form. Note that the proof isn't complete, so you can't end it with `Qed.` quite yet. I just want you to see what premises are available and what the output type should be.

Comment: I tried to use it with Compute and it failed because of Proof.

Comment: I don't understand, how to use the Proof mode here. Your explanations are too brief, and it's nowhere in the book. Please, look at the update. I think, ?I am on the right way here. But how to write the correct constructor for n?

Comment: `n` is a function rather than an element of an inductive type, so to use it, you'll apply it to some arguments (like `n X f x` in my answer). There won't be any recursion in the solution.